# Annoying newline issue with MacVim

Tags: vim, svn, macvim

A lot of times when I open a file with MacVim and close it, without doing any saving, SVN always shows that the file was modified.  Upon doing **svn diff** on the file, I get something like this:

```
-</script>
\ No newline at end of file
+</script>
```

What configuration settings do I need to add so that MacVim can play nicely with SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a particular MacVim issue; the file in Subversion does not have a trailing final newline (EOL), but Vim always adds one. Some applications (also several text editors) create files without a final EOL, many people argue that these files are broken, but nonetheless do they exist.

If you cannot agree in your team to avoid committing such files into Subversion, you have to work around the problem in Vim. If you do not `:write` the file at all, Vim should not touch it, but even a `:w` on an otherwise unmodified file will add the final EOL.

To better deal with those kind of files, I have written the [PreserveNoEOL plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4550).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and plugin! What is the reason for Vim always adding a newline? Is that just a Vim legacy thing? A *nix thing?

Comment: Most will argue it's the _right_ thing, but yes, it comes from Unix. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16224292/813602) is one explanation; you'll certainly find many more discussions on the web.